# Parsing Outlook pst with tika

Tags: outlook, apache-tika

I am new to Tika and working on parsing outlook files. Using Outlook Extractor I can parse the 
*.msg file but not *.pst. 
Is it possible to parse pst file with tika? If yes how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you asked the question, it wasn't then possible. The [Tika Enhancement request - TIKA-623](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-623) for adding PST support was only resolved in Tika 1.6. For older versions of Tika, you'd have to take the patch from there. (All the dependencies are now in Maven Central - that was the key blocker for a long time)

For users of Apache Tika 1.6 or later, the good news is that PST support is built in, and [PST is now one of the supported mail formats](http://tika.apache.org/1.8/formats.html#Mail_formats) in Tika!

Comment: Thank for the information, I will look into the patch and try sorting out the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

pst File parser is available with Tika 1.6

https://tika.apache.org/1.6/api/org/apache/tika/parser/mbox/OutlookPSTParser.html

Download latest jar from 
http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tika/tika-app/